# Flow types - map Object of functions to function results

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to type a function with flow which, given an Object type, accepts an object where each property is replaced by a "create" function creating the value. I expected to be able to map the value types using `$ElementType` typed to the `$Keys`, but it doesn't appear to be properly associating keys and values.

Here's a simplified example:

```
// @flow

type TestType = {
  foo: number,
  bar: string,
}

declare function create<
  K: $Keys<TestType>,
  V: $ElementType<TestType, K>,
  O: {[K]: () => V}
>(obj: O): TestType

const tmp = create({
  foo: () => 5,
  bar: () => 'whatever',
})
```

But flow reports that each type is incompatible with the value of the opposite key. E.g. `foo`'s value is incompatible with `bar`'s:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ tmp/syntax/flowTest.js:15:14

Cannot call create with object literal bound to obj because number [1] is
incompatible with string [2] in the return value of property foo.

 [2]  5│   bar: string,
       :
     11│   O: {[K]: () => V}
     12│ >(obj: O): TestType
     13│
     14│ const tmp = create({
 [1] 15│   foo: () => 5,
     16│   bar: () => 'whatever',
     17│ })
     18│
     19│ // type TodoValues = {
     20│ //   todos: Array<string>,


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ tmp/syntax/flowTest.js:16:14

Cannot return 'whatever' because string [1] is incompatible with number [2].

 [2]  4│   foo: number,
       :
     13│
     14│ const tmp = create({
     15│   foo: () => 5,
 [1] 16│   bar: () => 'whatever',
     17│ })
     18│
     19│ // type TodoValues = {
```

Live example: [Try Flow REPL](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AFSwM4q6Y4C8oA3oqKJLLAFygB2ArgLYBGWATgDQ1QXAIa9mRXgEsWAc0EBfZABMsAY2hickNizUopsFqDW8sIlFgA8QgNLMAJLaxoCV-ERLYAfINoA1RwBRaCwOLBZiUndCKOx+UFtfIQB5ZkoAbVsAXWYACgBKUDJvUH8lbzzYLgArZhSC5g84rGQ1IyJQFA4MYpMzCyw86lp6JlBC4tKAVj9hMXyiktAAcngAC0GANz4VxQKgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Flow [`$ObjMap` example](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmap) is pretty close to what you want. It basically works out of the box (renaming `run` to `create`):

```
// let's write a function type that takes a `() => V` and returns a `V` (its return type)
type ExtractReturnType = <V>(() => V) => V;

declare function create<O: {[key: string]: Function}>(o: O): $ObjMap<O, ExtractReturnType>;

const o = {
  foo: () => 0,
  bar: () => 'foo',
  baz: () => true,
};

type TestType = {
  foo: number,
  bar: string,
  baz: number, // Error since true is not a number
}

const p: TestType = create(o);
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEBsFMBcHIGdQHcBOBLalQENQDMBXAOwGNo0B7I0aATwActoALbaG7Aa0kVwAMAFAEpQAXgB8oAGp8cRACagUMAiiK9QfGaAEZEy6Kup1GQgFAmsAUQAe0FNjIAlFWoAqDLKNAAeKeIFhMUkpEQlpAG4zM3lIEnBsZXxiMkpqEmU2SB8AeQAuUABvAG1uWgL4ezQiAHMAXQKAMRTyKgBfAIoCnKECgBIcgCMAKwBZbHpcgBpQW3tHaBdDd09xKLMSKkrQCjEis1B8Ci6dMMkABimD0EHEgqDw2Dxj2CvD24Ave7OaFAJIK5tKKHQ4WTygNw8aAeRh7QrXZ4nIgEAC2g0gKDeNzuoEq6FqWM+BWRaIxgOuoM26nY9AKkMqMK8oAykCyAgoQgiQA)

Comment: Ah, yes, that's just what I was looking for. Thanks! I can make a follow up question unless this is simple, but any idea how I could make the values of o allow for values OR functions arbitrarily? e.g. `const o = { foo: () => 5, bar: 'barrrr'}`

Comment: Try this out. I'm not confident that it's completely safe, but it seems like it works for the most part ([Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbAEoWAV0QOwBVxoBeKAHgDUA+ACgYEopSaormAfd519gbgBQggCYRUAG2SJoAMxz50ASwD2+KKhnJgECgHkAXFADeAX3oqjexkYAkegEYArALLIw+gDSwEKdFlwCYkgaIUFUNQBnYCgVFhNBKChZFUsoOl42AAZPRKgHaSMMljYAchSVUtykgoAvIyQcCFzTMNBIKEIIaOCyBKSKo3wcAFsHCERq-MKoaMQlfABzKbqjB1SJCGR8FuEI-GioMCMunpJ4zS2dOhVGfiA))

Comment: I haven't found any way that it's not safe so far. Simpler than I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just one of those two *properties* `foo` / `bar` can be passed to `obj` *param* of *function* **create**. You can't put them together because you have `UnionType`.

```
K: $Keys<TestType>, // UNION: number | string
V: $ElementType<TestType, K>, // UNION: foo | bar
O: {[K]: () => V} // UNION: foo: () => number | bar: () => string
```

This works:

```
type TestType = {
  foo: number,
  bar: string,
}

declare function create<
  K: $Keys<TestType>,
  V: $ElementType<TestType, K>,
  O: {[K]: () => V}
>(obj: O): TestType

const foo = create({ foo: () => 5 })
const bar = create({ bar: () => 'whatever' })
```